# WildFly 18 deployment fails for (.ear) deployment file size more than 2GB

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, size, wildfly

I am trying to deploy the EAR file which has a size of more than 2GB in the WildFly 18 domain master server using jboss-cli.bat.

```
deploy deployment.ear --server-groups=server-group-app
```

The outcome of the deploy command shows success but the content file creates inside the domain/data/[hexcode] folder after deploy command has 0KB size.

[Size of the content file becomes 0kb after deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EXlW.png)

And the same EAR file when I try to deploy using master management console running on 9990 port, it also deploys successfully and the content file creates inside domain/data/[hexcode] folder has actual deployment size which is more than 2GB

[Size of content file same as EAR file after deployment through management console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDuel.png)

But it gives the following error on slave server startup in slave's host-controller.log file

```
2021-03-12 15:57:15,143 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Host Controller Service Threads - 4) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("server-group" => "server-group-app"),
    ("deployment" => "deployment.ear")
]): java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYHC0057: Failed to get file from remote repository
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnectionService$5.getFile(RemoteDomainConnectionService.java:813)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnectionService$RemoteFileRepository.getFile(RemoteDomainConnectionService.java:790)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnectionService$RemoteFileRepository.getDeploymentRoot(RemoteDomainConnectionService.java:784)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnectionService$RemoteFileRepository.getDeploymentFiles(RemoteDomainConnectionService.java:776)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.controller.operations.deployment.ServerGroupDeploymentAddHandler.execute(ServerGroupDeploymentAddHandler.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:999)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:743)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1413)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:423)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.internalExecute(AbstractControllerService.java:494)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.DomainModelControllerService.access$1100(DomainModelControllerService.java:202)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.DomainModelControllerService$InternalExecutor$1.lambda$apply$0(DomainModelControllerService.java:1416)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.access.InVmAccess.runInVm(InVmAccess.java:63)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.DomainModelControllerService$InternalExecutor$1.apply(DomainModelControllerService.java:1416)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.DomainModelControllerService$InternalExecutor$1.apply(DomainModelControllerService.java:1413)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.SecurityActions$Execution$1.execute(SecurityActions.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.SecurityActions.privilegedExecution(SecurityActions.java:47)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.DomainModelControllerService$InternalExecutor.execute(DomainModelControllerService.java:1419)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnectionService.applyRemoteDomainModel(RemoteDomainConnectionService.java:603)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnectionService.access$1200(RemoteDomainConnectionService.java:138)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnectionService$3.applyDomainModel(RemoteDomainConnectionService.java:546)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnection.applyDomainModel(RemoteDomainConnection.java:325)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnection$RegisterSubsystemsRequest$1.execute(RemoteDomainConnection.java:468)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementRequestContextImpl$1.doExecute(ManagementRequestContextImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementRequestContextImpl$AsyncTaskRunner.run(ManagementRequestContextImpl.java:160)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: JBTHR00005: Operation failed
    at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.get(AsyncFutureTask.java:253)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnectionService$5.getFile(RemoteDomainConnectionService.java:811)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:192)
    at org.jboss.as.repository.RemoteFileRequestAndHandler.handleResponse(RemoteFileRequestAndHandler.java:109)
    at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnectionService$GetFileRequest.handleRequest(RemoteDomainConnectionService.java:747)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:321)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler.handleRequest(AbstractMessageHandler.java:286)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:234)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelReceiver.handleMessage(ManagementChannelReceiver.java:85)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel.lambda$handleMessageData$3(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:430)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(EndpointImpl.java:991)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2021-03-12 15:57:15,159 ERROR [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Host Controller Service Threads - 4) WFLYHC0143: Failed to apply domain-wide configuration from master host controller. Operation outcome: failed. Failure description {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-416" => "WFLYCTL0158: Operation handler failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYHC0057: Failed to get file from remote repository"}}
```

So, is there a way with which I'll be able to deploy my EAR deployment file which has a size of more than 2GB in WildFly 18 domain master server using jboss-cli.bat?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: That's a huge EAR. Are you packaging some libraries, like the Java EE dependencies, that are not required?

Comment: No...We have some help related files and videos in some of the folders as a part of the deployment and we are migrating our existing JBoss6 setup to WIldFly18. In JBoss, as we have folder structure format, we were keeping all files in the same folder and now while migrating we are taking all folders available in jboss server and bundling them into ear file and deploying the same on our wildfly18 domain mode server